# Posting photos to a Facebook page as a non-admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

A client wants the ability for people to upload photos from within their website and have them post to their Facebook page. I'm personally an admin of the Facebook page in question, so I can post the photo myself without issue. However, I'm trying to determine if there is a way for a non-admin to post a photo to an album within the page.

Originally, there was an offline_access scope which would allow me to get a single access token (logged in as myself) to be used on the third party website, but this is no longer the case. It's looking more and more like there is no way to write any kind of information to a Facebook page (including wall even wall posts) via the open graph api *unless* you're an admin and have a manage_pages enabled token.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need `manage_pages` permission.  You want `publish_stream`.

manage_pages just allows you to obtain an access token to "log in as" an admin to a page the user has access to.  Publish stream allows you to make comments and post on people's wall.

With `publish_stream`, you should be able to post pictures to the pages wall as long as that page's permissions allow you to do so.  You won't be able to upload them to the pages album though, as that needs to be performed by an admin to the page.  Just like your friends can post pictures to your wall, but they can't add photos to your albums.

Using the graph protocol, you can perform any action that both:

1. The user you're authenticated as has permission to perform
2. Your application has been granted permission to perform on the user's behalf.

So it's important to understand both the permission settings of both the actor (authenticated user) and the victim (the object being changed).

Comment: That makes sense for the photo albums. Is there any way to perform these actions _as_ the page itself, or would that require an admin of the page to be logged in?

I've been really confused by the access_token with the recent deprecation of offline_access. With this in place, how could somebody programmatically pull content from Facebook for display on a website without having to manually renew the token every 2 months or whatever it is? And it seems awkward to have somebody authorize an application in order to view wall posts on a third party website, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You will first have to authenticate as one of the admins with "manage_pages" permission.  Then you can get an access token for the page you want to act as by calling https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts.  Using that access token will log you in as the page itself.

Comment: Yeah... I messed around with that and was able to use the page access tokens to do that stuff, so I can live with that being the case. Any insight on the second half of my question? When offline_access was still available, I would generate a token and drop it into my PHP script to use to pull in wall posts for a third party website, which would work indefinitely (and still does). Maybe this isn't the best way to do this in the first place, but with offline_access now deprecated, I'm not really sure how to do this at all without 1) manually updating the token often, or 2) forcing a user login.

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to force the user to login occasionally.  I still use offline_access in my projects, but I've updated them to check the access token before attempting to use it, and force a login if it's expired.

Comment: That seems so bizarre to me that you would have to have a user login in order to view information (from a public page) that's unrelated to them and won't be performing any sort of function on behalf of the user. Twitter, for example, will allow you to pull in tweets from a public user without even needing so much as an api key. I can totally understand why an access_token is necessary if you're posting on behalf of the user, but a read-only function of public information... that makes no sense to me. I feel like there HAS to be a better way to do that. :/